# How to Customize IdentityServer views in Blazor?

Tags: identityserver4, blazor-server-side, blazor-client-side, blazor-webassembly

I Have Project with Blazor Web assembly and  Asp.Net Core Hosted with Individual user account (Authentication).
but I have two problems. First I want Customization Register and log in View (relate to identity server 4), but I can't find views. in the server project (blazor server) in `_LoginPartial.cshtml` view, we can see many pages: `asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Manage/Index"` and`asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Logout"` , `asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Register"` and so on ... but Identity folder is empty ! also in blazor client we have `LoginDisplay.razor` page :

```
<NotAuthorized>
    <a href="authentication/register">Register</a>
    <a href="authentication/login">Log in</a>
</NotAuthorized>
```

and in Pages folder we have `Authentication.razor` Component :

```
@page "/authentication/{action}"
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication
<RemoteAuthenticatorView Action="@Action" />

@code{
    [Parameter] public string Action { get; set; }
}
```

`Authentication.razor` Component calling IdentityServer4 indirectly.

How can I find identity server 4 views and change it?

and the second problem is when I want to use a custom identity models in startup file blazor server.

default code is :

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

and when i change to:

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser,Role>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

when I run project and click on login or register buttons (`Authentication.razor`) call IdentityServer (ex:`https://localhost:5001/Identity/Account/Register?returnUrl=%2Fauthentication%2Flogin`), take me an error :

> Sorry, there's nothing at this address.

and I don't  no why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Server project, Add New Scaffolded Item dialog, select Identity > Add.

Comment: Any ideas for change texts "You are logged out", "checking login state" and "authorizing"? I suppose this has to do with with IdentityServer4. I really need this... Thanks a lot.

Comment: @ArthurB Watching images in [this post](https://virgool.io/@espiar/%D8%B3%D9%81%D8%A7%D8%B1%D8%B4%DB%8C-%DA%A9%D8%B1%D8%AF%D9%86-identityserver4-ui-vyyncneeck6b), if you can not find these words, you must be searching in client blazor project. (This is my personal opinion.)

Comment: Thanks @sda2584541, I already did that, but those text are shown when app starts, when redirect to login and when you logged out, those texts I suppose are embedded in some place, I wanna think that can be overriden, but I cant find where.

Comment: @ArthurB I do not know too. But if I understand, I will let you know.

Comment: @ArthurB I found how to customize "authorizing" text, you must go to the "App.razor" file in **client project** and between `AuthorizeRouteView` create a new `Authorizing` tag and between that write new custom text. for ex: `<AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
               <Authorizing>
                   <p>YOUR CUSTOM TEXT HERE</p>
               </Authorizing>
        </AuthorizeRouteView>`

Answer (score 6):

I just know how to custom the texts "You are logged out", "checking login state" and so on.

According to [the doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.webassembly.authentication.remoteauthenticatorview?view=aspnetcore-5.0), you can change the render fragment to anything you want by set the parameter of `RemoteAuthenticatorView` component.

There is 9 different render fragment you can customize:

1. `CompletingLoggingIn`
2. `CompletingLogOut`
3. `LoggingIn`
4. `LogInFailed`
5. `LogOut`
6. `LogOutFailed`
7. `LogOutSucceeded`
8. `Registering`
9. `UserProfile`

For example, if you want to change the text while you are logging in, just do this:

```cs
// BlazorApp.Client.Pages.Authentication.razor

@page "/authentication/{Action}"
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication

<RemoteAuthenticatorView Action="@Action" >
    <LoggingIn>
        I'm Logging in!!          // here
        <img src="/loading.gif /> // and more!
    </LoggingIn>
</RemoteAuthenticatorView>
```

Comment: "According to the doc"... its a stretch calling these docs.